# Re-ordering Columns in Datagridview VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to swap columns 1&2 with columns 6&7 for display. This is the code I have but it doesn't work?

```
dgvListings.Columns(1).DisplayIndex = 6
dgvListings.Columns(2).DisplayIndex = 7
dgvListings.Columns(6).DisplayIndex = 1
dgvListings.Columns(7).DisplayIndex = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the property

```
dgvListings.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

prior to setting the column order.